# How can i get windows username in vue flask app?

Tags: python, vue.js, iis, flask

I'm developing a web app with Flask and Vuejs (deploy on IIS) and i want to get the remote windows username without login on my application. How can i do that?
i try the following flask rest api but doesn't work. (with IIS configuration: Authentication - Anonymous Authentication ENABLED the result is REMOTE_USER "")

```
@app.route('/username', methods=['GET'])
def user():
    data = request.environ.get("REMOTE_USER")
    return jsonify(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get value from REMOTE_USER, please enable windows authentication instead of anonymous authentication.

If you enable anonymous authentication only,  IIS will never receive REMOTE_USER request variable.

When you enable windows authentication, client will always pass authenticated user via REMOTE_USER.

you could set IE to automatic login with current username/password.  So that client can sign in your website automatically.

However, it is impossible to get username without change configuration and permission on client side.